# How to use a single amplify backend for multiple apps in a Mono repo?

Tags: aws-amplify, monorepo, turborepo

I have created two react apps inside a Mono repo and I want to use a single amplify backend to the both apps. where should I `amplify init` in my Mono repo.

Answer (score 0):

You should init Amplify at the root of your workspace.

I use [Nx](https://nx.dev) for managing the Monorepo, and this is my foldr structure:

amplify

apps

- app1
- app2
- app3

amplify.yml

Check also [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/946)